# ¿Como debugear una app react native en un dispositivo android?

Tags: react-native, depuración

Estoy intentando hacer debug en visual studio code, con la extensión React Native Tools, versión de react native: "~0.63.4", agregue el archivo launch.json con la configuración Debug Android.
Hago click en Debug Android, se instala la app pero luego se cierra y termina el proceso.

Obtengo estos mensajes:

```
Launching the application
Attaching to the application
Starting debugger app worker.
Se estableció conexión con el proxy (empaquetador) a la aplicación React Native
Debugger worker loaded runtime on port 19471
```

y:

```
[Info] --------- beginning of main


[Info] 07-19 23:35:04.888 14703 14951 I ReactNative: [GESTURE HANDLER] Tearing down gesture handler registered for root view com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView{b4b0c54 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,2260}


[Info] --------- beginning of crash
```

No se porque pueda estar sucediendo esto